# dispatch_async in NSManagedObjectContext's performBlock

Tags: ios, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

According to the WWDC 2012 video, "Core Data Best Practices", `dispatch_sync` should be used to run some kind of callback in `performBlock` of context, which is created as a type of `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.

Why is that?

Can I use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 0)`... to call some UI-related callbacks in  private queue's context's `performBlock`?

Answer (score 4):

No.  `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` manages it's own internal queue, and does not enjoy you trying to leave one of it's threads to do what you want to do (in fact, I believe it throws exceptions when this type of behavior occurs).  There's a few ways of handling this, of course signalling semaphores being the more acceptable design pattern to get the truly "async feel", but as you note, `dispatch_sync` is usually the way to go.

Comment: actually my app using dispatch_async in performBlock and in most cases it doesn't cause any problem. :( that's why I'm so curious of whether I have to dispatch_sync. btw, does dispatch_async hand over control to other thread? I think I'd better study GCD again.

Comment: Well, it does if you specify a different thread (like the main thread).

Comment: then it's safe to call dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()... in, actually at the end of, performBlock of context of NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, of course.  It's just that performBlock: is an MOC-specific method, and Core Data's golden rule is "one context per thread."

Answer (score 0):

Google got me here, so if anyone is new to this stuff as I am, and would benefit from a code example, here is one:

```
__block dispatch_queue_t currentQ =  dispatch_get_current_queue();

[managedObjectContext performBlock:^{

    //do the stuff you need to do in a background thread

    dispatch_sync(currentQ, ^(){

        //callback code for once the background stuff is complete

    });
}];
```

Comment: The code above is syntactically correct, but I suspect not for the right reasons. Generally, one calls dispatch_sync in a performBlock: to update the UI, i.e. to tell a view or viewController that the data has changed and that the display needs to be updated. These calls *must* take place on the main thread. Your currentQ may be the main queue, but it may also not be. Therefor the safe way is: __block 'dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();' followed by dispatch_sync(mainQueue, ^(){ //update UI });'